# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SupervisingPhysician'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

In PatientViewModel

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SupervisingPhysician { get; set; }
```

In PatientController

```
// Supervising Physicians
List<SelectListItem> listSelectSPListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (Physician physician in db.Physicians.Where(p => p.IsSupervising == true))
{
    SelectListItem selectSPList = new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = physician.FirstName +" "+ physician.LastName,
        Value = physician.Id.ToString()
    };
    listSelectSPListItems.Add(selectSPList);
}
ViewBag.SupervisingPhysicians = new SelectList(listSelectSPListItems,"Value","Text");
```

In View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SupervisingPhysician, (SelectList)ViewBag.SupervisingPhysicians, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-4" })
```

Error:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SupervisingPhysician'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ViewData item that has the key 'XXX' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)

Comment: Slightly different error message but same issue as the dupe - it means `ViewBag.SupervisingPhysicians` is `null` (probably because you return the view in the POST method but have not reassign the `ViewBag` property). And its a bit pointless to create a second identical SelectList from the first one - it should be just `ViewBag.SupervisingPhysicians = listSelectSPListItems;`